# Are there matrices such that $AB=I$ and $BA \neq I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Are there matrices such that $AB=I$ and $BA \neq I$ ?

$A$ and $B$ are square matrices

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With square matrices, no. With non-square matrices, it's perfectly possible. For example,
\begin{align*}
A &= \left(\begin{array}{ccc}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0\end{array}\right) \\
B &= \left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{array}\right)
\end{align*}
Note that, indeed, we cannot have non-square matrices where $AB$ and $BA$ are identities of appropriate dimensions, because that would imply the existence of an isomorphism between spaces of different dimensions!

Comment: With non-square matrices, one of $AB = I$ and $BA=I$ is impossible.

Comment: Sorry Robert, I didn't see your comment before I edited!

Answer (score 3):

If $AB=I$ with $A,B$ square matrices, then $\ker(B)=\{0\}$. Therefore $B$ is also surjective by rank-nullity, so $B$ is invertible and $A=B^{-1}$, so $BA=I$.

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ and $B$ are finite square matrices (of size $n\times n$), then $$AB=I_n\implies BA=I_n$$
However, if $A$ and $B$ are not square, if $AB=I_n$, then $BA\neq I_n$ in general (and $BA$ need not even be the same size as $AB$).

This [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix) may provide more information on invertible matrices.

Comment: If $AB$ is square, then $BA$ is defined, and square (but not necessarily the same size).

Comment: @Aweygan yes. I was more thinking about arbitrary matrices $A$ and $B$, but since $AB$ is square $BA$ is defined as you say. However the main point that $BA\neq I_n$ in general still holds. I will edit, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to your question: Assuming $A,B$ are squares, the answer is there are none.

Claim: Let $\mathbb F$ be any field. If $A,B\in \mathbb F^{n\times n}$, then $AB=I$ implies $BA=I$.

Proof:
We first show that $A$ is nonsingular. Suppose otherwise. Then there exist elementary matrices $E_1,\ldots, E_k$ such that 
$$E_k\cdots E_1A=C$$
where $C$ has a zero row. Then
$$E_k\cdots E_1AB=CB$$
has a zero row. The matrix $AB=I$ is row equivalent to $CB$, which is absurd since $I$ has no zero row. Thus, $A$ is nonsingular.

Since $A$ is nonsingular,
$$B=(A^{-1}A)B=A^{-1}(AB)=A^{-1}\cdot I=A^{-1}.$$
Hence, $BA=I$ too.

Comment: I am not sure this is a helpful explanation, because you are assuming some properties of nonsingular matrices which OP may or may not know.  For example, when you write $A^{-1}$, you seem to be assuming that $A$ has a two-sided inverse to begin with.

Comment: I disagree. I think this is more helpful for a beginning linear algebra student. If OP is taking a linear algebra course, it is more likely that he/she has seen properties of nonsingular matrices before the rank-nullity theorem.

Comment: FYI, when I wrote $A^{-1}$, I already proved $A$ is nonsingular. This proof actually shows that it does not matter what the underlying field is. I think that is helpful.

Comment: What is your definition of nonsingular?